# Java and robots

Tags: java, regex

So i made my first bot in java and im very happy with my result 
but i want my bot to be more advanced so may i get some help !

heres my code

```
        Robot a = new Robot();
    for ( char C : "i like codding".toCharArray() ){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
   int n = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(C);
    a.keyPress(n);
    a.keyRelease(n);
```

i want to change [i like codding] to whatever between this sign >< . for example

```
        Robot a = new Robot();
    for ( char C : char.matches("><").toCharArray() ){
         c.replaceAll("><"," ");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
   int n = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(C);
    a.keyPress(n);
    a.keyRelease(n);
```

so as you see its wrong , i dont know why , my idea is that my bot will read whatever written between > < and rewrite it again. 
for Example :

! >  Example1   <

Bot will type : Example1

Comment: I think you should start with more basic things than bots. Like understanding the syntax of the for loop in your first code - and then understanding why substituting the string with `char.matches("><")` is not possible.

Comment: i think its string , thats rly not matter i know loops...etc , my own problem is to understand the logic of how it should work

Comment: You might want to extract the string between `>` and `<` _before_ the loop, i.e.  `String replaced = input.replaceAll(".*>(.[^<])<.*","$1");` then use `replaced` in your loop. Just note that this is somewhat fragile, e.g. if there are multiple `>text<` in the input. You need to handle that (which might mean not using regex at all) or make sure the input always meets the requirements.

Comment: @Thomas still error </3

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the matches method is wrong. matches() is a string method that returns a boolean for whether or not a sequence appears in the string, using regex to check for patterns. Right now you're using char.matches("><"), but there is no such method in char as it is a primitive, and there is no such method in the object Character.

What you're looking for is to use the matches method before the loop, with a regex statement that looks like something Thomas commented. More importantly however you should try and focus on learning some of the basics like the differences between objects and primitives, loop structures, string manipulation, and method return types. These are all easy, but large topics that make up the fundamentals of programming; like RealSkeptic said, I recommend starting out with an easier project, and to add to this, I recommend going through the Oracle Java tutorial that should bring you up to speed relatively quickly: [Oracle Java Tutorial Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

Comment: see , im using loops and calling object wrong because i dont know the logic of these case , i didnt deal with this in collage , i mean these kind of manipulation. thats why im asking for it , i couldnt understand the logic behind this . so if you be kind to show me how to . it would be nice of you sir <3